# Why am I getting a "floating point exception" from an all-integer calculation?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

    // Variables 
    int option, numerator1, denominator1, numerator2, denominator2;
    int resultNum, resultDenom, reducedNum, reducedDenom, gcd;
    int i, m; 

    //Input
    scanf("%d %d/%d %d/%d", &option, &numerator1, &denominator1, &numerator2, &denominator2); 

    //Error handling: checking if option is not 1 2 3 or 4
    if (option > 4 || option < 1) {
        printf("The first value must be 1, 2, 3, 4.\n");
    }
    //Error handling: checking if the denominator is < 0
    else if (denominator1 == 0 || denominator2 == 0) {
        printf("Denominators cannot be zeroes.");
    }
    //Error handling: checking if any integers are negative
    else if (numerator1 < 0 || numerator2 < 0 || denominator1 < 0 || denominator2 < 0) {
        printf("Cannot have a negative number.");   
    }   

    else {
        //Addition  
        if (option == 1) { 
            resultNum = numerator1*denominator2 + numerator2*denominator1;
            resultDenom = denominator1*denominator2;
            //Getting the greatest common divisor
            for (i = 1; i < resultDenom; i++) {
            if (i % resultNum % i == 0 && i % resultDenom == 0 ) {
                gcd = i;
            }  
            }
            reducedNum = resultNum / gcd;
            reducedDenom = resultDenom / gcd;
            //Checking if it's a whole number
            if ( reducedDenom == reducedNum) {
            printf("%d\n", reducedNum/reducedDenom);
            }
        //Outputting the fraction if it's not.
            else {
            printf("%d/%d\n", reducedNum, reducedDenom);
            }
        }

        //Subtraction
        else if (option == 2) {
            resultNum = numerator1*denominator2 - numerator2*denominator1;
            resultDenom = denominator1 * denominator2;  
            //Getting the greatest common divisor
            for (i = 1; i < resultDenom; i++) {
                if (i % resultNum == 0 && i % resultDenom == 0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
            }
            reducedNum = resultNum / gcd;
            reducedDenom = resultDenom / gcd;
            //Checking if it's a whole number
            if (reducedDenom == reducedNum) {
                printf("%d\n", reducedNum/reducedDenom);
            }
        //Outputting the fraction if it's not
            else
            printf("%d/%d\n", reducedNum, reducedDenom);
        }

        //Multiplication
        else if (option == 3) {
            resultNum = numerator1 * numerator2;
            resultDenom = denominator1 * denominator2;
            //Getting the greatest common divisor
            for (i = 1; i < resultDenom; i++) {
            if (i % resultNum == 0 && i % resultDenom == 0) {
                gcd = i;
            }   
            } 
        reducedNum = resultNum / gcd;
        reducedDenom = resultDenom / gcd;

        //Checking if it's a whole number
            if (reducedNum == reducedDenom) {
            printf("%d\n", reducedNum/reducedDenom);
            }
        //Outputting the fraction if it's not   
            else {
            printf("%d/%d\n", reducedNum, reducedDenom); 
        }
        }

        //Division
        else {
        resultNum = numerator1 * denominator2;
        resultDenom = denominator1 * numerator2;
        //Getting the greatest common divisor
        for (i = 1; i < resultDenom; i++) {
            if (i % resultNum == 0 && i % resultDenom == 0) {
            gcd = i;
            }
        }
        reducedNum = resultNum / gcd;
        reducedDenom = resultNum / gcd;
        //Checking if it's a whole number
        if (reducedNum == reducedDenom) {
            printf("%d\n", reducedNum/reducedDenom);
        }
        //Outputting the fraction if it's not
        else {
            printf("%d/%d\n", reducedNum, reducedDenom);
        }
        }
    }   


    return 0;
}
```

It will compile and wait for input, but when I put in the numbers it just gives me the message *floating point exception* and won't do anything. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input that causes the crash? Or does it occur with any and all inputs?

Comment: It occurs with any and all inputs

Comment: Always check the return value from `scanf()`; it will tell you whether the values you specified were read.  Next, especially when debugging a problem, print the values that were read, to make sure the computer knows what you typed is what you thought you typed.  Also, use a function to calculate the GCD, and print it out since you are getting errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You don't mention which compiler you're using, or which OS. Regardless, there's a debugger available for almost all of them. Have you tried using it? (You posted no sample inputs, no indication of where the problem might be, or anything else other than "I'm getting a floating point error" and a bunch of code.)

Comment: Floating point exception is a historical misnomer. Basically it means division by zero, or sometimes `(-1)/INT_MIN`.

Comment: @R..: under what circumstances would (-1)/INT_MIN not yield 0?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Probably a typo and R.. meant `INT_MIN/(-1)`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I wrote it backwards. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) calculation is:

- repeated when it should be in a separate function, and
- inefficient compared with one of the oldest (300 BCE) known algorithms in the world, Euclid's algorithm for finding the GCD of two numbers.

Further, your miscalculation of it is causing your 'floating point' (or, in this case, 'divide by zero') error.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the already mentioned inefficiency, you have your remainder calculations backwards,

```
for (i = 1; i < resultDenom; i++) {
    if (i % resultNum == 0 && i % resultDenom == 0) {
        gcd = i;
    }
}
```

(and in option 1, you even have a nonsensical `i % resultNum % i == 0`). Since in the calculation, you always have `1 <= i < resultDenom`, every time `i % resultDenom` evaluates to `i`, thus the `if` condition is never satisfied, and `gcd` never gets set.

However, you unconditionally divide `resultNum` and `resultDenom` by `gcd`.

Thus you're using an uninitialised variable, which in your case perchance contained 0 (not surprising, since it's common that the OS hands zeroed memory to a new process) and caused the (misnamed) floating point exception by a *division by zero*.

To fix it with minimal code changes, make the condition

```
if (resultNum % i == 0 && resultDenom % i == 0)
```

in all `gcd`-calculations. But you should heed @Jonathan Leffler's advice and use the Euclidean algorithm to calculate greatest common divisors.

Answer (score 0):

`Floating point exception` arises when you try to modulo by 0 i.e. `myNumber % 0`.

See if you have such case in your code... Try to print all numbers that you are generating after calculation and check it...

Comment: `i % resultNum % i == 0` would probably cause this.

Answer (score 0):

For example in your addition part:

```
    reducedNum = resultNum / gcd;
    reducedDenom = resultDenom / gcd;
```

`reducedNum` and `reducedDenom` may be 0

and what result do you expect by writing `i % resultNum % i == 0` ?